# BandWidth Monitor

Tags: monitor, bandwidth

New to Ubuntu, I want a application which monitor my Bandwidth usage in GUI for Particular time. Is any application is available for my requirement?
For ex: If I need to monitor for a month at a specific time 10 to 6.

Please share your views.

Comment: Do you want it to monitor in a specific interface or just the one being used by you?

Comment: Hi Alex, I need to monitor for broadband usage for a specific time. Any software is available for ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command line program `iptraf` for this purpose. It has great user interface. I'm sure that you would love it.

And, here are some more bandwidth monitoring tools
`bmon`
`bwbar` 
`bwm`
`bwm-ng`
and
`iftop`

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for one too.  I saw something called ntm but I am not sure i trust it.
Gnome system monitor seems to be the only stock thing I can find.
iptraf seems weird