# wireshark crashes when using flow graph feature ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireshark

Using the flow graph feature on wireshark Version 1.10.6 causes wireshark to crash. I am running wireshark on ubuntu 14.04,

Comment: Are you opening a pcap file or are you doing a live capture? Wireshark usually has quite bad performance when it comes to live captures and there's a lot of traffic (you can use any of the suggested tools in http://askubuntu.com/questions/330393/bandwidth-monitor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this problem is corrected in the last version, 1.12. You can install it following these instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireshark-dev/stable
sudo apt-get update                             
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I checked quite quick all the 1.12.x release notes and couldn't find any fixed bug related to flow graph, https://www.wireshark.org/docs/relnotes/.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wireshark/+bug/1311173